# PHP Image Crop from the top, bottom, left & right

Tags: php, upload, crop

H Guys,

I'm ui=sing this code to upload and crop images.  Handily when I put it together originally the centre of the crop was in the middle of the image and it works splendidly!

I'd like to increase functionality by adding the option to crop instead of cropping a centred image crop from the top or left side or bottom.  This would be chosen from radio boxes on the previous page.

I've seen some rather complex ways of doing it but wondered if there was a simple way of achieving it, any thoughts? Thank you.

```
$handle->image_resize           = true;
$handle->image_ratio_crop       = true;
$handle->image_convert          = 'jpg';
$handle->image_x                = $x;
$handle->image_y                = $y;
$handle->jpeg_quality           = 75;
$handle->Process( $dir_dest );
```

From form on previous page:

```
    <label for="artwork">Banner Artwork</label>
<div class="input-group upload-crop">
    <input class="upload-button" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" name="<?=$strNameInput?>" id="<?=$strNameInput?>" type="file" />
    <label><strong>Crop from:</strong></label>
    <label for="centre">Centre</label><input checked type="radio" id="centre" name="crop" value="centre" /> 
    <label for="right">Right</label><input type="radio" id="right" name="crop" value="right" /> 
    <label for="left">Left</label><input type="radio" id="left" name="crop" value="left" /> 
    <label for="top">Top</label><input type="radio" id="top" name="crop" value="top" /> 
    <label for="bottom">Bottom</label><input type="radio" id="bottom" name="crop" value="bottom" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I used a POST variable called crop (from the radio buttons), if no radio buttons were chosen it centres the crop, if not it uses T, B, L or R

```
$strCrop = $_POST['crop'];

    $handle->image_resize           = true;
    if ( $strCrop == '' ) {
        $handle->image_ratio_crop       = true;
    } else {
        $handle->image_ratio_crop       = $strCrop;
    }
    $handle->image_convert          = 'jpg';
    $handle->image_x                = $x;
    $handle->image_y                = $y;
    $handle->jpeg_quality           = 75;
    $handle->Process( $dir_dest );
```

It uses a fancy bootstrap browse button now:

```
   <div class="btn btn-default btn-file pull-left">
        Browse<input class="upload-button" style="display:none" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" name="<?=$strNameInput?>" id="<?=$strNameInput?>" type="file" />
    </div>
    <label><strong>Image crop:</strong></label>
    <input checked type="radio" id="centre" name="crop" value="" />
    <label for="centre">Centre</label>
    <input type="radio" id="right" name="crop" value="R" />
    <label for="right">Right</label>
    <input type="radio" id="left" name="crop" value="L" /> 
    <label for="left">Left</label>
    <input type="radio" id="top" name="crop" value="T" />
    <label for="top">Top</label>
    <input type="radio" id="bottom" name="crop" value="B" />
    <label for="bottom">Bottom</label>
```